# Why is MacBook connecting to network with weaker signal despite stronger (other) network being available?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, wifi

I can connect to different networks depending on where in the building I am. Some are stronger than others depending on where I am.

The MacBook has credentials for all networks.

Often it chooses a weaker one and sometimes fails entirely without bothering to autoconnect to another one that does still have signal.

Why does it do this and how can I stop it from happening?

Answer (score 2):

Your Mac is joining networks based on its list in System preferences: Networks : Advanced,

So change the preferred order by dragging the ones you want to the top:

[image]

Comment: Note: this setting will be shared to your iPhone/iPads too.

Comment: And then this will need to be changed each time you change location.

Comment: @Thinkr not really, my macbook pro picks up my home network or my work network quite happily - I never have to change it...

Comment: Ok, I thought you would need to change each time. ;)

Comment: Ah interesting, I thought iOS/MacOS was doing something clever to connect to the strongest/fastest network as appropriate.